# A metric space of which the geodesic is not a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, geodesic

The text book in my course has an exercise about finding a metric space whose (usual) length metric is not a metric. It wants me to find a metric space $(X,d)$ satisfying $d'(x,y)=0 \ \ $for some distinct $x,y\in X$ ; $d'$ is a length metric.

In my conclusion, such a metric space doesn't exist.

The followings are some definitions in the problem set (and my 'wrong' solution).

Thanks in advance!

---

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space.

(1) For a continuous map $ α:I=[0,1] → X$, we define the $length$ of $α$ as
$$l(α) = \sup{\sum_{i=1}^{k}
d(α(t_{i−1})), α(t_i))},$$
where the supremum is taken for all finite sequences $\{t_i\}$ satisfying
$0 = t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < · · · < t_k = 1$. If the supremum is finite,
we say $α$ is $rectifiable$.

(2) Define for $x, y ∈ X$,
$$d'
(x, y) = \inf \ l (α)$$
where the infimum is taken over all rectifiable curves joining $x$
and $y$. We call $ d'
$ as the $length\ metric$ on $X$.

---

;;;Suppose such a metric space exists

$\exists \ x,y \in X \ $ s.t. $\ 0=d'(x,y) < d(x,y)$

By the definition of $d'(\cdot,\cdot)$,

$\exists \ a \ rectifiable \ curve \ \gamma \ joining \ x \ and\  y \ $s.t.$ \ d'(x,y) \leq l(\gamma)<d(x,y) $

However, $$l(\gamma) \geq \sum_{i=1}^{k}
d(\gamma(t_{i−1})), \gamma(t_i)) \geq d(\gamma(t_0)), \gamma(t_k)) =d(x,y)$$ holds for all finite sequences $\{t_i\}$ satisfying
$0 = t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < · · · < t_k = 1$ (for some positive integer $k$) 
;Which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: It is OK. This actually shows that the strict inequality $d'<d$ cannot hold.

Comment: why do you have  $d′(x,y)≤l(γ)<d(x,y)$ ?

Comment: It's because I think $d'(x,y)=\inf l(\alpha)=0$means ,'for arbitrary $c>0, \ \exists \  a \  rectifiable \ \alpha \ $ s.t. $\ 0  \leq l(\alpha)<c$'.

Comment: The problem set contains three exercises and in the first one I proved there is a property $d\leq d'$ if (there exsits a rectifiable curve joining any two points in the metric space $\ X$) & ($d'(x,y)$ is not zero for distinct  $\ x,y\in X$). since what I posted is the second one, I thought that constructing such a metric space might be possible if I ignore the two assumptions above

Comment: I got the revised version of the problem, and the above solution is right, thanks again for all of your help